# Override plugin template

Tags: plugins

I've got Recent post by category widget on my plugin with the folder "recent-posts-by-category-widget" I've copied that folder and all of it's contents to the root location of my theme. But the override is not working, I've already done this on woocommerce and no issues happening there.

Would love some ideas to fix this issue.

Comment: WooCommerce has the override functionality built into their code, which is why you can copy to your theme. The plugin does not have that same functionality. What are you trying to change?

Comment: Oh, I thought wordpress has this override functionality throughout. Basically the layout and data being presented will be changed.

Comment: Here's a solution, you can take a look: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257942/overrides-plugin-files-on-wordpress-themes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work like that as native functionality, a plugin author has to build that themselves, and some have such as WooCommerce and Shortcodes Ultimate. If your plugin doesn't have this functionality and the hooks available (if any) aren't sufficient, you'll need to fork the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for this info, I've seen some WP guides copying function classes to functions.php would that work?